# Hide default style class of p:selectOneRadio

Tags: css, jsf, xhtml

I have used `p:selectOneRadio` in my xhtml page but I am not being able to remove their default style class `.ui-helper-hidden-accessible`, hence the radio button icons are not being visible.
My code is as follows:

```
<p:selectOneRadio
     id="whetherRegisteredThroughEdistrictApp"
     layout="grid" value="#{loginMBean.whetherCitizenUser}"
     required="true" requiredMessage="#{i18n['errmsg-req-fields']}"
>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="#{true}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="#{false}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" update="notcitizenUserDiv, citizenUserDiv" />
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Why would you want this? The component becomes unusable then. Use a plain jsf selectoneradio instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Javascript is the best way to do:

```
$( '#yourDivName input[type="radio"]' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
```

or you can find with id end disable the disable attribute.

```
var radio = $('[id$=radio] input');
radio.attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: I shall try this but is there any way of disabling the class using css?